# Python pandas: change only next unnamed column with the previous column name

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any method to give next unname column with previous column only for next one column.

input:

```
ca~                         ch~     
Campaign Type   Code    Channel Type    Code    Channel Type Definition
```

Output:

```
    ca~             ca~     ch~             ch~
    Campaign Type   Code    Channel Type    Code    Channel Type Definition
```

i tried with below but its filling all blanks, though i only want to fill right next column not another blank.

```
x.columns = x.columns.to_series().mask(lambda y: y.str.startswith('Unnamed')).ffill()
```

Comment: channel type definition should be blank?

Comment: @PV8 yes, so i only want to fill next column, not another unnamed next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample

```
             ca~ Unnamed           ch~ Unnamed.1                Unnamed.2
0  Campaign Type    Code  Channel Type      Code  Channel Type Definition
```

one way to do this

```
df.columns = [df.columns[i-1] if 'Unnamed' in df.columns[i] else df.columns[i] for i in range(len(df.columns))]
```

---

```
             ca~   ca~           ch~   ch~                Unnamed.1
0  Campaign Type  Code  Channel Type  Code  Channel Type Definition
```

**Alternative**

first replace 'Unnamed' with NaN and then ffill with limit = 1

```
df.columns = list(pd.DataFrame(df.columns).replace('Unnamed\.?\d?',np.nan,regex=True).ffill(limit=1)[0])
```

---

```
    ca~   ca~           ch~   ch~                      NaN
0  Campaign Type  Code  Channel Type  Code  Channel Type Definition
```